# Sending Messages from cmd to winform application

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-messages

I have an applicaion in Winform and this application is launched from cmd. I want to launch my winform application once and like to send messages to winform application. Also, when I like to close my winform application from cmd.

I have written the Winform application in C#.

Please guide me.

Thanks in advance.

-Harsha

Comment: Why in the world are you launching a Windows Forms application from a command prompt? I don't understand what you are trying to accomplish here.

Comment: @Cody Gray. The aim in not trivial but I cant seen anything strange in it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should use function [FindWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633499%28VS.85%29.aspx) and [SendMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644950%28VS.85%29.aspx). Also you should overide WindProc in your C# application to process input messages.

Comment: Thank you very much. Finally, I created one more console application and sending messages to my winform app.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure why you would want to do what you just described. But if you are looking at a generic way to control a winform application from another application, you can take a look at named pipes(.NET 3.5+).
Otherwise you can do this by using a tcp socket in loopback mode.

Comment: Thank you saibal. I will also look at named pipes.